# Java stream match as many predicates as possible

Tags: java, java-stream, predicate

Looking to filter a list depending on some criterias define as Predicate (below are just examples):

```
Predicate<Person> agePredicate = p -> p.age < 30;
Predicate<Person> dobPredicate = p -> p.dateOfBirth < 1980;
Predicate<Person> namePredicate = p -> p.name.startWith("a");

List<Predicate<Person>> predicates = Arrays.asList(agePredicate, dobPredicate, namePredicate);

List<Person> shortListPersons = listPersArrays.asList(listPersons).stream().filter(p -> predicates.stream().allMatch(f -> f.test(p))).limit(10).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

In the situation I cannot find anyone/enough people, how can I get a list of people who match as many criterias as possible - a sort of ranking.

My other option is to call again the same function as above but using a anyMatch instead but it won't be very accurate.

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with the code given from your question:

```
List<Predicate<Person>> predicates = Arrays.asList(agePredicate, dobPredicate, namePredicate);
```

We can sort a list of people by the count of predicates they match:

```
List<Person> sortedListOfPeopleByPredicateMatchCOunt = 
  listPersArrays
    .asList(listPersons)
    .stream()
    .sorted(
      Comparator.comparingLong(p -> predicates.stream().filter(predicate -> predicate.test(p)).count()))
       // Reverse because we want higher numbers to come first.
       .reversed())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Amazing! That's exactly what I had in mind but I didn't know how to do it with predicates.

Answer (score 1):

Just an extension to the above answer, if your goal is to filter a collection matching as many criteria as possible, you can create a composite `Predicate<Person>` and then use it for filtering.

Given your list of predicates:

```
List<Predicate<Person>> predicates = Arrays.asList(agePredicate, dobPredicate, namePredicate);
```

Composite predicates can be created like this:

```
Predicate<Person> compositPredicate = predicates.stream()
                .reduce(predicate -> false, Predicate::or);
```

> NOTE: As reduction operation requires an identity value and `or`
>   operation of `Predicate<>` class doesn't apply any further predicates if
>   any one predicate turns out to be `true`, I've used `predicate -> false` as
>   an identity value.

Now, filtering the collection becomes easier and cleaner:

```
List<Person> shortListPersons = persons.stream()
                                       .filter(compositPredicate)
                                       .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Doesn't directly answer the question, but +1 for a `reduce` on the predicates. You could do something similar to reduce the predicates to a value given a `Person` and then sort by the given `Function`.

Comment: This feels very elegant, but I wonder if a similarly elegant looking solution can be found which will self terminate more effectively. The documentation says reduce does this:

T result = identity;
     for (T element : this stream)
         result = accumulator.apply(result, element)
     return result;

which for my variation of usage which is to test each element of a large list passes a variable set of filters, is less efficient than

     for (T element : this stream)
         if !accumulator.apply(result, element) return false;
     return true;

If that all makes sense